# Why does my fluid have all this colors after baking? I assume it's a density/ velocity map but don't know how to disable it

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image]

Even in render view mode this colors appear. When taking a closer look they are actually particles on top of the liquid.

Comment: You mean that blue, green and red? That is weight paint that fluid generates when moving that is telling you what is moving (basically it means that red particles are moving fast and green/blue are moving slower) it is only for viewport and it wont be visible in render ... I am not even sure if you can turn it off or not

Answer (score 1):

It actually is visible in render mode but I've figured it out. I had the box "velocity" checked on the domain and that for some reason creates this particle system to tell what you said. Just unchecking it solves the problem.